# How to get and assign entire column form Database to individual button's text?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to get all the values of entire column in a table and to assign them to individual button text.

This is what i have achieved so far.

```
            string query = "SELECT type FROM service";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                button5.Text = reader[0].ToString();
                button6.Text = reader[1].ToString();
                button7.Text = reader[2].ToString();
                button8.Text = reader[3].ToString();
                button9.Text = reader[4].ToString();
                button10.Text = reader[5].ToString();
                button11.Text = reader[6].ToString();
                button14.Text = reader[7].ToString();
                button15.Text = reader[8].ToString();
                button16.Text = reader[9].ToString();
                button17.Text = reader[10].ToString();
                button18.Text = reader[11].ToString();
            } con.Close();
```

I can only assign one value to the button5, how do i get all the values?

Comment: if i understand correctly then you could make a string variable and append values to it: var x = ""; x+=reader[0].ToString();x+=reader[1].ToString(); ... and so on

Comment: nope not working either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this `if(reader.Read())` to `while(reader.Read())`.

If checks if rows are present, while iterates through the reader.

You can create an array of buttons:

```
Button[] btnArray = {Button5, Button6,... and so on}
```

Then use the while condition:

```
int i=0;
while(reader.Read())
{
    String name = reader.GetString(0);
    btnArray[i].Text = name;
    ++i;
    if(i == btnArray.Length) break; //Jus in case there are more values in reader than in array.
}
```

And don't forget to close the reader.    reader.Close()